# How to plot a simple terminology tree in R using the most suitable approach

Tags: r, tree, plot

I need to plot this structure in R:

```
(1000) Diseases of the genitourinary system 
    (1580) Nephritis, nephrotic syndrome, and nephrosis 
        (580) Acute glomerulonephritis
            (580.9) Glomerulonephritis, acute, unspec.
        (581) Nephrotic syndrome
            (581.9) Nephrotic syndrome, unspec.
        (582) Chronic glomerulonephritis
            (582.9) Glomerulonephritis, chronic, unspec.
        (583) Nephritis and nephropathy, not specified as acute or chronic
        (584) Acute renal failure
            (584.5) Renal failure, acute w/ tubular necrosis
```

as a nice jpg/pdf/(or other) which will have nodes, connections and labels using R of the structure above.
I looked at libraries which require GrafViz installed and had no luck so native solution (e.g., using ggplot2) would be best. I was not able to put together the code using igraph. I am also new to graphics in R with no textbook based foundation. Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

The structure above is only example. Other structure might have 50+ concepts to plot and printed as very large PDF/poster. The plot would be static (no interaction with it using mouse).

Comment: Can I try and explain this better? Is it correct to assume that you are giving this input data and it will be available as a text file? And your output? Can you sketch what it would look like? A [dendrogram](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/dendrogram.html)? Or [other tree structure](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html)?

Comment: The data is provided in two files. One CSV file (concepts) has all the concepts without any hierarchy. Another CSV file has all the relationships (in this case only 'is-child-of' relationship. concept1 is child of concept2. This image is close to the problem: http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/images/tree.pdf  but a child relationship may skip generation (e.g., edges can go not only to immediate neighbors

Comment: Unable to answer (I am on iPad now) but I suggest you post a snippet of the second file as it should be possible to go from that to the output you need and someone will answer it quite quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an effort at an answer. It is an approximation to what you need and the final result looks like this:

[image: Terminology tree]

I made this in `igraph` and the code uses a simulation of the type of data that you describe.

```
library("igraph")

vertex.df <- read.table(text = "id    code  name
0   1000    'Diseases of the genitourinary system '
1   1580    'Nephritis, nephrotic syndrome, and nephrosis '
2   580 'Acute glomerulonephritis'
3   580.9   'Glomerulonephritis, acute, unspec.'
4   581 'Nephrotic syndrome'
5   581.9   'Nephrotic syndrome, unspec.'
6   582 'Chronic glomerulonephritis'
7   582.9   'Glomerulonephritis, chronic, unspec.'
8   583 'Nephritis and nephropathy, not specified as acute or chronic'
9   584 'Acute renal failure'
10  584.5   'Renal failure, acute w/ tubular necrosis'",
                        header = TRUE,
                        stringsAsFactor = FALSE)

vertex.df$code <- as.character( vertex.df$code )

edge.df <- read.table(text = "from    to
0    1
1   2
1   4
1   6
1   8
1   9
2   3
4   5
6   7
9   10",
                      header = TRUE)

edges <- matrix(c(edge.df$from, edge.df$to), nc=2)

g <- graph.empty()
g <- add.vertices(g, nrow(vertex.df),
                  id=vertex.df$id, 
                  code=vertex.df$code, 
                  name=vertex.df$name)
g <- add.edges(g, t(edges))


plot(g, 
     layout = layout.kamada.kawai,
     vertex.label = V(g)$code,
     vertex.size = 35,
     vertex.color = "white",
     vertex.label.family = "sans")
```

I use the ICD Code as vertex label. This is because the long text of the disease names looks untidy when plotted at this scale.

When plotting, you can change the `vertex.label` parameter to `V(g)$name` if you want the disease name instead of the ICD code. I suspect that if you print to a large pdf and remove the vertex outlines, you may be able to get a nice looking tree. Look at `?igraph.plotting` for the details on parameters that you can change.

I hope it gives you a step up in your experimentation.